# Images into a template in Django 1.8

Tags: python, django, image, templates

Im using Python 3.4, and Django 1.8

Im trying to display an image in a Django Template! Im using the next code:

In settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIR = (r'C:\Users\CesarAlfonso\Desktop\DocBOok\cuenta\static')
```

In my template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static "cuenta/celeste.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/>
```

But this doesn't work! 
The image celeste.jpg is saved in the static files specified direction!
HELP!

Comment: Development or production server?

Comment: Development!! @Wtower

Answer (score 1):

Your STATICFILES_DIR should look like this:

```
STATICFILES_DIR = ('C:/Users/CesarAlfonso/Desktop/DocBOok/cuenta/static',)
```

Note that the slashes were switched from `\` to `/`, `r'` was removed and added a comma at the end. `r'text'` means its a raw string:

> such strings are called raw strings and use different rules for interpreting backslash escape sequences

and the comma at the end makes it a tuple.

UPDATE:

> Note that these paths should use Unix-style forward slashes, even on Windows (e.g. "C:/Users/user/mysite/extra_static_content").

from the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS)

Comment: If i make that change, when I run my server it bring me this error:
syntax error (unicode error) 'unicode escape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \uxxxxx escape